# Reagentc.exe in condition

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I write this code to create WinRe partition, I need to check if it is already existed before start creating it, so I want some command can be added before this code to check its status, I do not want to do it manually, I need it fully automated, not just reagentc.exe /info, if any one can help,
Thanks

```
REM Create WinRE partition
(echo sel vol c
echo shrink desired=665 minimum=650
echo cre par pri size=665 id=de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac
echo format fs=ntfs quick label=WinRE
echo assign letter=z
echo gpt attributes=0x8000000000000001
)  | diskpart

REM copy recovery image to the new patition
MkDir "Z:\Recovery\WindowsRE" 
Xcopy /H "C:\Recovery\WindowsRE\WinRE.wim" "Z:\Recovery\WindowsRE"
ReAgentC /Disable
ReAgentC /SetREimage /Path "Z:\Recovery\WindowsRE"
ReAgentC /Enable

REM Hide WinRE partition
(echo sel vol z
echo remove
)  | diskpart

ReAgentC /Info
pause
```

Comment: You are not describing what your issue is. I am not going to run your script to change partitioning on my system just to see what issues you are having. Please clarify your unclear question.

Comment: I write this code to create WinRe partition, I need to check if it is already existed before start creating it, so I want some command can be added before this code to check its status, I do not want to do it manually, I need it fully automated, not just reagentc.exe /info, if any one can help, Thanks

Comment: but to check the status of what? That is what I need to know.

Comment: I need to check the status of WinRE partition, before start creating it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
$recinfo = reagentc /info
$recinfo2 = $recinfo[3]
$recstatus = ($recinfo2 -split "\:", 2)[1]
$recstatus
```